# use of php system function

Tags: php, whm

I've always avoided using program execution PHP functions. From all the searching and reading I've done, it seems as though I have no choice but to use the system function to unzip a password protected ZIP file.

Is this truly still the only option where there is no PHP library that can unzip a password protected file?

If I do have to use the system function, is there a way to limit its usage to just the command I will need or something else I can do to prevent any potential vulnerabilities. I have a VPS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are nice extensions like [Zlib](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zlib.php) and [Zip](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) for handling compressed files in PHP but you can't create or extract password protected files with these extensions.

You need to find a 3rd party library (i don't know is there any lib exists) to achieve that or simply continue to use program execution.

Also you may want to make some experiments with [passthru()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) to keep disable `shell_exec` or `system` like dangerous methods.

Comment: The passthru() function is less dangerous then? How do I not have the raw output display?

Comment: Ended up sticking with using shell_exec since it didn't display the raw output.